# How do I change default compaction strategy in cassandra/scylla?

Tags: cassandra, scylla

I've read that you can set compaction strategy per table in Cassandra/Scylla, as described here https://docs.scylladb.com/operating-scylla/procedures/config-change/change_compaction/

The default compaction strategy is Size-tiered compaction strategy (STCS).

But is there a way to change it somehow, in the settings, such that each table that's created uses another compaction strategy by default?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compaction strategy is a sub-property of the compaction configuration of each table so you will need to use the CQL `ALTER TABLE` command to choose a different compaction strategy other than the default.

In almost all cases, the `SizeTieredCompationStrategy` (STCS) is the right choice and so it is the default. There are very limited cases where you would choose a different compaction strategy.

The most common situation where you would change it is if you have a time-series use case where `TimeWindowCompactionStrategy` (TWCS) is recommended. `LeveledCompactionStrategy` (LCS) is only valid for workloads were there is very little writes and your app is almost exclusively doing reads.

So unless you fit into these narrow use cases, STCS should be your choice of compaction strategy. Cheers!

Comment: Yea, I need the TimeWindowCompactionStrategy. I find is bizarre that Cassandra doesn't include a global mechanism to change this and requires you to set this per table. All my tables require TimeWindowCompactionStrategy and it's annoying to set all this per table. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Do you have any ideas about how to automate this? Maybe there's a way to configure some kind of events in cassandra, such that when a table is created that "ALTER TABLE" statement gets triggered automatically and sets the right strategy?

Comment: You can actually specify the compaction properties when you create the table. For example: `CREATE TABLE table_name ( ... ) AND compaction = {'class': 'TimeWindowCompactionStrategy'}`. Cheers!

Comment: If you already know that you need TWCS, you don't need to `ALTER TABLE` -- just specify TWCS when you create the table. Cheers!

Comment: I am afraid that my project has lots of developers and when a new developer creates a table, they will forget to set the strategy, or something. This requires every developer to keep this in mind.

Comment: I understand but making a cluster-wide setting configurable hasn't gained traction in the past (CASSANDRA-12209, CASSANDRA-13552) for various reasons but feel free to add your voice to the second ticket. Having said that, I'm more concerned that "lots of developers" make schema changes which is asking for trouble. 

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12209
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-13552